# Magento 1.9 CE - Enable HTML links in error/custom messages

Tags: error, ce-1.9.0.1, custom, html, tags

I would like to know if this is possible to enable HTML links in custom messages (ie: error messages).

Here is my example: I've made an override for my needs of Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item/Item.php

```
Function checkQuoteItemQty :

if (!$this->checkQty($summaryQty) || !$this->checkQty($qty)) {
     //$message = Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('The requested quantity for "%s" is not available.', $this->getProductName());
     $message = Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('The requested quantity for "%s" is not available (max:%s).', $this->getProductName(), ($this->getQty() * 1));
     $cat_id = $this->getProduct()->getCategoryIds();
     if($cat_id){
         $url = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id[0])->getUrl();
         $message .= Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('You might be interested in <a href="%s">those products</a>.', $url);
      }
      $result->setHasError(true)
           ->setMessage($message)
           ->setQuoteMessage($message)
           ->setQuoteMessageIndex('qty');
     return $result;
}
```

But the HTML link I created in $message :
(*$message .= Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('You might be interested in those products.', $url);*) 
is not clickable and considered as text (because of the translation I guess...). Is it possible to change this behavior?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who would like to know, I had to override Mage_Core_Block_Messages, line 249 :

```
public function getGroupedHtml()
    {
        $types = array(
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::ERROR,
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::WARNING,
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::NOTICE,
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::SUCCESS
        );
        $html = '';
        foreach ($types as $type) {
            if ( $messages = $this->getMessages($type) ) {
                if ( !$html ) {
                    $html .= '<' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . ' class="messages">';
                }
                $html .= '<' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . ' class="' . $type . '-msg">';
                $html .= '<' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . '>';

                foreach ( $messages as $message ) {
                    $html.= '<' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . '>';
                    $html.= '<' . $this->_messagesContentWrapperTagName . '>';
                    $html.= ($this->_escapeMessageFlag) ? $this->escapeHtml($message->getText()) : html_entity_decode($message->getText());
                    $html.= '</' . $this->_messagesContentWrapperTagName . '>';
                    $html.= '</' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . '>';
                }
                $html .= '</' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . '>';
                $html .= '</' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . '>';
            }
        }
        if ( $html) {
            $html .= '</' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . '>';
        }
        return $html;
    }
```

Adding a html_entity_decode at this line :

```
$html.= ($this->_escapeMessageFlag) ? $this->escapeHtml($message->getText()) : html_entity_decode($message->getText());
```

Just let me know if you find a better solution.

Comment: I found the addition of `html_entity_decode` unnecessary. All I needed to add to the relevant controller action was: `$this->getLayout()->getBlock('messages')->setEscapeMessageFlag(false);`