# Add markup to out of checkout/cart stock message

Tags: cart, messages, out-of-stock, global-messages

I have copied `/app/code/Core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php` to `/app/code/local/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php`. At line (aprox) 580 the following code exists

```
if (!$this->getIsInStock()) {
        $result->setHasError(true)
            ->setMessage(Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('This product is currently out of stock.'))
            ->setQuoteMessage(Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('Some of the products are currently out of stock.'))
            ->setQuoteMessageIndex('stock');
        $result->setItemUseOldQty(true);
        return $result;
    }
```

I need to edit the text inside the `setQuoteMessage` function to include `<a href="/shop">continue shopping </a>`. There seems to be some kind of escape html function hitting it between it leaving this file and it getting to the view templates because no matter what I try doing the browser just displays the `a tag` as regular text.

For session messages I've found [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewt%20../viewthread/176933/) option where you just set `$session->setEscapeMessages(false);`. Is there any kind of similar param I can add on the `$result` which will do the same.

I have tried using the session messages instead but it means that I lose functionality in terms of product specific messages and message position based on the product that is out of stock. So adding a flag to the original code and the updated text would be my absolute preferred solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a bit of a hack and the link @tecjam provided I've got a dirty but working solution.

In `/app/code/local/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php` inside the function `checkQuoteItemQty` at the parts where qty messages get set I set a session variable;

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCartCheckoutErr(true);
```

Then having copied `Mage_Core_Block_Messages` to `/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Messages.php` I went to the function `getGroupedHtml()` at line 229 and modified it like so;

```
public function getGroupedHtml()
{
    $types = array(
        Mage_Core_Model_Message::ERROR,
        Mage_Core_Model_Message::WARNING,
        Mage_Core_Model_Message::NOTICE,
        Mage_Core_Model_Message::SUCCESS
    );
    $html = '';
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        if ( $messages = $this->getMessages($type) ) {
            if ( !$html ) {
                $html .= '<' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . ' class="messages">';
            }
            $html .= '<' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . ' class="' . $type . '-msg">';
            $html .= '<' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . '>';

            foreach ( $messages as $message ) {
                $html.= '<' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . '>';
                $html.= '<' . $this->_messagesContentWrapperTagName . '>';
                $html.= ($this->_escapeMessageFlag) ? $this->escapeHtml($message->getText()) : $message->getText();

     ================================**MY CHANGES**============================================   

                 if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCartCheckoutErr()){
                    $html.= ' Email ' . Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_sales/email') .' or <a href="/shop">continue shopping </a>';
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsCartCheckoutErr();
                }
================================**MY CHANGES**============================================

                $html.= '</' . $this->_messagesContentWrapperTagName . '>';
                $html.= '</' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . '>';
            }
            $html .= '</' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . '>';
            $html .= '</' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . '>';
        }
    }
    if ( $html) {
        $html .= '</' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . '>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

It was important to add in some logic to only add the markup in certain situations because obviously I don't want it added every time an error is rendered. However this may not be required for everyone and in such cases a cleaner solution could be more easily attained.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

The answer can be found here:

[Magento 1.9 CE - Enable HTML links in error/custom messages](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36145/magento-1-9-ce-enable-html-links-in-error-custom-messages)

The rest of this answer can be disgarded.

---

An example on how this can be done can be found here:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml
```

---

```
<p><?php echo $this->__('Your order # is: %s.', sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $this->escapeHtml($this->getViewOrderUrl()), $this->escapeHtml($this->getOrderId()))) ?></p>
```

-- edit:

So you can use 2 functions like above, or hardcode it:

```
->setQuoteMessage(Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('Some of the products are currently out of stock. %s', sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', '/shop', 'continue shopping')))
```

---

The functions are defined here: /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Success.php:

```
/**
 * Retrieve identifier of created order
 *
 * @return string
 * @deprecated after 1.4.0.1
 */
public function getOrderId()
{
    return $this->_getData('order_id');
}


/**
 * Get url for view order details
 *
 * @return string
 * @deprecated after 1.4.0.1
 */
public function getViewOrderUrl()
{
    return $this->_getData('view_order_id');
}
```

Comment: Unless i'm misunderstanding this, all that's happening differently is that you suggest adding the extra info to the message with `sprintf`? This doesn't change the `escapehtml`. Also the success page always has the same message so doing it in the template won't affect any other scenarios.

Comment: Yes, I belive that's true. you can simply do this in the template: `<p><?php echo $this->__('Your order # is: %s.', sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', '/shop', 'continue shopping')) ?></p>`

Comment: this will break the other messages tho! I still need the others to work as normal

Comment: Have you tried this: `->setQuoteMessage(Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('Some of the products are currently out of stock. %s', sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', '/shop', 'continue shopping')))`

Comment: yeah and it still displays the markup as text - the only difference in that and what i was doing originally is how the line is constructed, not what happens afterwards.

Comment: I'm sorry, in that case I don't know how to avoid the sanitising of these messages - it's something I'd also like to know =)

Comment: no worries, cant blame a guy for trying to answer :)

Comment: This may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25640623/magento-enable-html-links-in-error-custom-messages

Comment: The link is a good direction to go in for this. It's not a stand-alone solution but got me there. You should probably delete the rest of the answer tho, I gave you an upvote for effort ;)